# Why does println() throw an error in one case but not in another?

Tags: kotlin

Why is it that

```kotlin
println(Int.MIN_VALUE + " " + Int.MAX_VALUE)
```

throws an error, while

```kotlin
println("" + Int.MIN_VALUE + " " + Int.MAX_VALUE)
```

does not?

Comment: The expression `Int.MIN_VALUE + " " + Int.MAX_VALUE` starts with an `Int` and a `+` afterwards expects and exclusively accepts a numerical data type. It will be evaluated to an `Int` (most likely). The expression `"" + Int.MIN_VALUE + " " + Int.MAX_VALUE` starts with a `String` and a `+` means concatenation when applied to a `String`, **not** addition as when applied to an `Int`.

Comment: In java if we place strign any side (left or right) of + it concats but in kotlin its not happening

Comment: That's how it is (at the moment). Kotlin is not Java, I think there's a reason for this design, but I don't know it ;-)

Comment: You are encouraged to use string template instead of using + to concat string anyway.

Comment: @deHaar Implicit conversions (not casts) are a source of many bugs in Java, so I assume this is why Kotlin disallows them. Same reason there's no fall-through behavior in when statements. Although fall-throughs can be helpful in Java switch statements, they are also a major source of bugs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Think so, too, but I can't proof it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, your two statements call different plus functions. The plus function is a [binary operator function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations), which means that it can be called using the [infix notation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation) `a + b`. This will call the operator function on `a`, with `b` as the argument. In your example, this means that

```kotlin
"" + Int.MIN_VALUE
```

calls the [plus defined by `String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html) which has `String.plus(other: Any?)` as its method signature. As mentioned by the documentation, it

> Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given other object.

This means that it will get the `String` representation of `Int.MIN_VALUE`, by calling the `toString()` method.

On the other hand,

```kotlin
Int.MIN_VALUE + ""
```

calls the [plus defined by `Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/plus.html) which limits the type of its argument and cannot be applied to a `String`, and thus Kotlin will throw an error.

---

As a side remark, you should probably use [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates) anyway:

```kotlin
"${Int.MIN_VALUE} ${Int.MAX_VALUE}"
```

Comment: @RahulSankhala If this answer helps you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so future users know it solved/explained your question.